# Distributional derivative of $\left|\cos|\pi x|\right|$

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

I am new to distributions and I have a problem finding the distributional derivative for the following function: $$\left|\cos|\pi x|\right|$$

I would be grateful if you could help to find the distributional derivative for this case. Please find the attached figure with this link.
[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ictl.png)

I have tried up to some extent and I have attached a figure of that one here too. However, I could not find a way to extend that solution. Please find that figure with this link.[attempt_one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5x24.jpg)

Comment: What did you try? If you show your work, i.e. any failed attempts, people on this site are more likely to help you out.

Comment: $\left|\cos|\pi x|\right|$ is the same as $\left|\cos(\pi x)\right|$ because cosine is an even function.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is continuous and piecewise $C^1$ then its distributional derivative is just $g(a)=f'(a)$ at the $a$ where $f$ is differentiable.

Comment: But of course the exercise must be primarily about what happens at the points where it is not smooth.

Comment: Nothing happens, $g$ is the distribution defined in my answer.

Comment: But it gets interesting when you look at $f''.\qquad$

Answer (score 1):

Since $f(x)=|\cos|\pi x||=|\cos \pi x|$ is continuous and piecewise $C^1$ the distributional derivative is just the ordinary pointwise derivative where it's defined:
$$f'(x) = \pi (-\sin \pi x) \operatorname{sign}(\cos\pi x).$$

The derivative is only piecewise continuous, piecewise $C^1$, and has steps from $-\pi$ to $+\pi$ at $x=\pm\frac12,\pm\frac32,\pm\frac52,\ldots$ It's derivative is therefore the pointwise derivative plus $-2\pi\delta(x-x_i)$ where $x_i=\pm\frac12,\pm\frac32,\pm\frac52,\ldots$:
$$f''(x) = -\pi^2|\cos\pi x| + \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\delta(x-\frac{2k+1}{2}).$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your support.